# jQuery is not defined even though it loads correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, class

I'm having issues using jQuery in my code. Looking at Chromes developer tools i see a status of 200 next to the jQuery library, so it seems to load correctly. Ive also ensure i load it before my `App.js` main javascript. Does anyone have any idea why im getting this error?

Heres my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />


    <!-- jquery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    //<![CDATA[

      src="../components/App.js"

    //]]>

  </script>
```

Heres where im using jQuery inside `App.js`:

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state= {fileChanged:false, fileChosenForComment:null, currentAuthor: null, files:null, fileChangeCounter:-1}
    }

    componentDidUpdate =()=>{

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {console.log('inside DidUpdate method');

            jQuery('#file-list').on('click', this.updateClickCounter);
        });
    }

    updateClickCounter = () =>{

        this.setState({fileChangeCounter:this.state.fileChangeCounter + 1}, console.log(this.state.fileChangeCounter))
    }
```

here is the render method inside the App class

```
render(){
        return (
            <div className = "ui container" >

                <div className = " ui relaxed grid">
                    <div className = "two column row">
                        <div className = " column uploader float right upload-button" >
                            <h2>File Uploader</h2>
                            <input 
                                type="file"
                                id = "my-file"
                                multiple 
                                onChange = {()=>this.sendFiles()} // this doesnt immediately call it cos ()=> is same as doing //function(){}. i.e same as defining it so not calling it here. and because function isnt called here (i.e havent done function(){}()) the inside (callChild()) wont be called
                            />  
                        </div>
                        <div className = 'column login'>
                            <h4> <LoginSection getCurrentUser = {(author)=>this.getCurrentUser(author)}/> </h4> 
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div className = "two column row">
                        <div className = "column float left file-list ">
                            <h2> File List </h2> {/* if no files selected display message, else send files to fileList child*/}
                            {!this.state.fileChanged &&
                                <h4>
                                 No files currently selected
                                </h4>
                             }
                            <FileList fileList= {this.state.files} onCommentButtonClick={this.onCommentButtonClick}/> {/* pass onCommentButtonClick as callback func to child*/}
                        </div>  

                        <div className="column">
                            <h2> Comment Section </h2>
                            <CommentSection 
                                selectedFile = {this.state.fileChosenForComment} 
                                currentAuthor= {this.state.currentAuthor} 
                                fileChangeCounter = {this.state.fileChangeCounter}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>


    )}
```

Comment: It's `<script src="../components/App.js"></script>` not what you've got

Comment: Why are you trying to make click event handlers with jQuery rather than using the proper react operators?  https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: I can't see the rest of your code but I'm going to take a guess and say that you need to add a jQuery.noConflict(true) somewhere. By default jQuery uses the $. If you didn't declare that jQuery replaces $ it will not work.

Comment: i added that to remove this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`. That was a suggested solution to the problem. The console.log still isnt firing though but i guess this is another issue

Comment: @Billy surely using jQuery instead of $ as i am doing means this doesnt matter?

Comment: @SeanBarker if anything else wants the global symbol `$` it certainly would matter.

Comment: @Pointy yes but with jQuery this wouldn't be an issue as long as i dont use $?

Comment: Using `jQuery` works fine. Anyway, do you have JSX in that React class? Because assuming you've fixed the `<script>` tag, you'll still need to package the React app modules into a single, browser-compatible script. The `<link>` in there suggests you're using `create-react-app`?

Comment: @ChrisG yes i do. I can add it to the original question

Comment: @Taplar ill take a look at that. Although it would still be good to work out what is wrong for future reference

Comment: @SeanBarker incorrect. jQuery will take over the value of `$` when you load it.

Comment: @Pointy ill look into using that then

Comment: This isn't going to work at all like that. First of all you aren't supposed to use jQuery and React together anyway. Especially not if the jQuery stuff you use can easily be replaced with React stuff. Next you need to use `yarn start` during development and `yarn build` when you're done. Remove the script tag you've inserted into `index.html`. webpack will compile all your modules into a single script and inject it into the HTML.-

Comment: @ChrisG yes im using create-react-app. I thought using the google CDN meant i wouldnt need to download any modules? I'm relatively knew to react and JS so apologies if im misunderstanding anything

Comment: If you absolutely must add jQuery to your app, yes, you can insert it like that. In addition you need to add `/* global jQuery */` after the import lines of any module that uses jQuery. This should prevent webpack from complaining about the undefined reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack, one thing you should do is to add this configuration:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    }),
  ],
```

Another thing you could try is using `window.jQuery` to access to jQuery global variable.

Finally you can use refs instead of selectors, I consider this more readable:

```
<div ref={(el) => { this.clickable = el; }}>click Me</div>

window.jQuery(this.clickable).on('click', this.updateClickCounter);
```